# My function is not keeping its variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to keep `var values` and add several more to it each time I pick a `li` but the `var values` resets itself each time.

I'm pretty sure I'm doing something wrong but I can't figure it out.

```
$( '#drop-down > ul > li' ).on( "click", function() {
    if (values === undefined)
    {
        var values = $( this ).text();
    }
    else
    {
        values = values + $( this ).text();
        console.log(values);
    }
    console.log('test' + values);
});
```

Comment: declare `var values;` before if/else statement

Comment: Where do you get values from? From your example, it will always be undefined in your function

Comment: I want the var values to be empty at the beginning and getting it to fill itself each time I click a li element and add it to the existing.

Answer (score 0):

if you define the values var in the function itself, it is only present in the scope of the function. Try to init the "var values" beforehand.